# Pause native C code running via JNI

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, signals

I'm running a Java application that in turn calls some C code.  From the Java, I create a thread whose only responsibility is to execute the call to the C code.

How would I pause the execution of the C code?  I've spent the day so far looking into it and I'm not sure if I should be trying to pause at the Java or C level.

Below I have the java code for the thread which calls `public native String beginTest()`.

```
public void run() {
    int result = this.beginTest();
    AmpTester.setResponseValue(result);
}
```

For simplicity's sake, let's say the JNI interface and native method are defined as follows:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_AmpTester_beginTest (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj){
    return startAmpTest();
}
```

And the actual native code I want to run:

```
int startTest(){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        printf("%i\n", i);
        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would pause in the code/same environment which created the thread.

Comment: I am not familiar with JNI, but you could  possibly add signal handlers to your C Code. You `signal(SIGURS1, pid)` which when handled would `sleep(some_predefined_time)`

Comment: I'm looking into multithreading the C code (depending how complicated that gets) and then basically having a "watcher" thread that would pause and resume the main thread with the signals.
My issue with your suggestion is I need pausing for an indefinite time, until a resume button or something is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Java's [`Thread.suspend()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#suspend%28%29) *probably* (depends on the JVM but I doubt that anybody would implement it like that) won't work, but I also wouldn't recommend it. You could use the operating system's [`SuspendThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686345%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, but I wouldn't recommend this either. Suspending a thread is bad:

> Thread.suspend is inherently deadlock-prone. If the target thread holds a lock on the monitor protecting a critical system resource when it is suspended, no thread can access this resource until the target thread is resumed. If the thread that would resume the target thread attempts to lock this monitor prior to calling resume, deadlock results. Such deadlocks typically manifest themselves as "frozen" processes.

Source: [Why are Thread.stop, Thread.suspend and Thread.resume Deprecated?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html)

And the windows `SuspendThread` function is primarily designed for use by debuggers (for similar reasons), according to the documentation. So basically the answer is that you shouldn't pause the execution of any code, including your  C code.

---

But you can solve your problem with an exclusive lock/mutex and a global variable: In every iteration of the loop, check if a global `volatile bool` variable is still `true`. If it isn't, acquire a lock, set it back to `true`, release the lock and then continue iterating.

Your `suspend()` function will look like this: Acquire the lock and set the variable to `false`.

Your `resume()` function will look like this: Release the lock.

You can invoke those functions via JNI.

Example: The native method is iterating (thread A). Now a thread B calls `suspend()`. It acquires the lock and changes the variable. Now thread A notices that and, in the process of acquiring the lock, waits until thread B releases it. Finally thread B calls `resume()` and releases the lock. Now thread A acquires it, changes the value, releases it and continues iterating.

Comment: I can't use your second suggestion because there's no loop in the thread running the C code.  It's just the function call.  Though I suppose I could "share" some sort of global boolean between the C and Java via JNI and have predefined possible "pause points" in my C code. 
I'll try implementing that idea.  I think it might work out.

Comment: Also, I may have been implementing it incorrectly, but it seemed that the code just ignored the Thread.suspend(), because I attempted to implement that.  It just blew by.  Perhaps once the native code gets control, it can't be stopped by Java, or isn't running as a Java thread?

Comment: As I said, using `Thread.suspend()` probably won't work. A JVM **might** implement it using the OS SuspendThread function, but all JVMs I know are using a mechanism similar to the one I suggested in my answer.